# oauth2 client credentials flow Cors Issue

Tags: reactjs, azure-active-directory, cors, adal, clientcredential

I'm trying to implement client credentials flow using [adal-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/adal-node) in my react app

Code I am trying

```
var AuthenticationContext = require('adal-node').AuthenticationContext;

const authenticate = (): any =>{   

    var authorityHostUrl = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com';
    var tenant = 'xxxx.onmicrosoft.com'; 
    var authorityUrl = authorityHostUrl + '/' + tenant;
    var applicationId = '2sdsdwewe-232jkdksdsdsadfsfdsdf'; 
    var clientSecret = 'sdfer245dwfsfw3rt345r342fwfwefwf'; 
    var resource = 'api://sdfwerwerwrwerwerwrewrwer'; 
    
    var context = new AuthenticationContext(authorityUrl);
    
    context.acquireTokenWithClientCredentials(resource, applicationId, clientSecret, (err: { stack: string; }, tokenResponse: any)=> {
      if (err) {
        console.log('well that didn\'t work: ' + err.stack);
      } else {
        console.log(tokenResponse);
      }
    });
}
```

I have running from my local which is `http://localhost:3000/`

So in Azure active directory app registration for the app, I have added `http://localhost:3000/` under web Redirect URIs. Also tried adding that under SPA as well

But when I run this it comes up with CORS error

`Access to fetch at 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxx.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

I am missing something here

When I run Chrome as `chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security`

this works and generate valid token

Comment: So you're trying to avoid cors problem? I'm not sure what's your goal and if you wanna to [generate token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-authentication-flows) in an SPA, you may use auth code flow or implicit flow(new Msal.UserAgentApplication) to avoid cors.

Comment: @Tiny-wa yes, as per my understanding if you specify correct redirect URI this shouldn't happen

Answer (score 1):

You can see this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-compare-msal-js-and-adal-js) to take a look at the differences between adal and msal. And if you decide to use msal.js to integrate authentication by azure ad, then you can't use client credentials flow as this flow is for [Daemon application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-authentication-flows).

I can offer you a [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65747678/how-access-a-secret-from-keyvault/65763064#65763064) that used Implicit grant flow in spa with msal.js, hope it can help, and I'll continue to find out the solution on adal.

And followed your link provided in question, I downloaded this [sample](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-nodejs/tree/master), and I
find that after I opened the sample code in vs code and modify the configuration in 'client-credentials-sample.js' , npm module and 'node sample\client-credentials-sample.js', I can get the response successfully, so I can't reproduce your issue. I didn't add redirect url.

[image]

On the other hand, if you wanna to resolve cors issue, you should edit your api program rather than this one, the same domain with different port also leads to cross-origin. And I created a java api application, I used filter to solve cores problems. And I'm new to node so that I'm not sure if [it](https://stackabuse.com/handling-cors-with-node-js/) can help to solve cors in nodejs.

```
@Order(Integer.MIN_VALUE)
@Component
public class CorsFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
      public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
          throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        res.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        res.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT");
        res.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type,X-CAF-Authorization-Token,sessionToken,X-TOKEN,Authorization");
        if (((HttpServletRequest) request).getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {
          response.getWriter().println("ok");
          return;
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
      }
      @Override
      public void destroy() {
      }
      @Override
      public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
      }
}
```