# MSAL.js infinite loop, not calling Microsoft Sign-In Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, oauth-2.0, msal.js

I am trying really hard to make MSAL work with Vanilla JavaScript, but it just doesn't work.

Whenever I am trying to click the Sign In button on the Login Page, the Login page just refreshes and nothing happens, the Microsoft Sign In Page is not being shown.

Also no errors are logged to console.

After clicking the Sign In button for like 200 or more times and page refreshing that many times, the Microsoft Sign In page shows up and then it works fine.

**Script reference**

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://alcdn.msauth.net/lib/1.4.4/js/msal.js" integrity="sha384-fTmwCjhRA6zShZq8Ow5ZkbWwmgp8En46qW6yWpNEkp37MkV50I/V2wjzlEkQ8eWD" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

**JS MSAL code**

```
//Config
const msalConfig = {
        auth: {
            clientId: "{Client ID}",
            authority: "{Authority}",
            redirectUri: "{Base App URL}/Dashboard", //This URL is registered in Microsoft AAD
            navigateToLoginRequestUrl: false
        },
        cache: {
            cacheLocation: "localStorage",
            storeAuthStateInCookie: true,
        }
    };

//Login Request Object
const loginRequest = {
        scopes: ["User.Read"],
        prompt: 'login',
    };

//Initialize MSAL
var myMSALObj = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(msalConfig);
myMSALObj.handleRedirectCallback(authRedirectCallBack);

//Handle Callback
function authRedirectCallBack(error, response) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            if (response.tokenType === "id_token") {
                console.log("id_token acquired at: " + new Date().toString());

                if (myMSALObj.getAccount()) {
                    showWelcomeMessage(myMSALObj.getAccount());
                }

            } else if (response.tokenType === "access_token") {
                console.log("access_token acquired at: " + new Date().toString());
                accessToken = response.accessToken;

                try {
                    callMSGraph(graphConfig.graphMailEndpoint, accessToken, updateUI);
                } catch (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                }
            } else {
                console.log("token type is:" + response.tokenType);
            }
        }
    }

$(document).on("click", "#btn-testing-msal", function () {
        myMSALObj.loginRedirect(loginRequest);
});
```

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm new to msal and I created a [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65747678/how-access-a-secret-from-keyvault/65763064#65763064), I think you could compare it with yours to analyze somewhere. And in my opinion, after clicking the login button many times the sign in page works, it seems that your code is fine, so have you debuged your source in browser's console panel?

Comment: Thanks!. I just checked in console, it doesn't show any errors

Comment: Thanks for your response and if you have any further finding or problems, pls feel free to let us know, maybe your problem here will help others.

Answer (score 0):

Debug your frontend code like this, just trying to make sure where caused your problem, and it may have some help:

[image]

Comment: I am actually trying to use loginRedirect method of MSAL, we cant use LoginPopup because browsers often disable popups, Thanks will try debugging and will let you know