# How to generate bearer token to activate PIM in azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am using the below REST API to enable azure PIM at the moment.

```
API endpoint : https://api.azrbac.mspim.azure.com/api/v2/privilegedAccess/azureResources/roleAssignmentRequests
Body: 
{
"roleDefinitionId":"sdfsa4324-7b46-sdfa234-8db9-c32423354",
"resourceId":"243-4a58-4sdf1e-a0f4-234234dfds",
"subjectId":"sdfasd-9af3-42f5-9699-dfasd243",
"assignmentState":"Active",
"type":"UserAdd",
"reason":"Evaluate Only",
"ticketNumber":"Evaluate Only",
"ticketSystem":"Evaluate Only",
"schedule":{"type":"Once","startDateTime":null,
"endDateTime":null,"duration":"PT0M"},
"linkedEligibleRoleAssignmentId":"2423asdf-c271-4342342-8859-11243dfsaf",
"scopedResourceId":null
}
```

The problem I am facing at the moment is I am not sure how to generate the bearer token automatically to pass as an authorization header. Currently, I am just fetching the token from the Chrome developer console. Can anyone help me to point an API in which I can use my creds and generate a bearer token which I can use for PIM?

Thanks,
Tintu

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I assume that you'd like to call an API to enable PIM, so you need an access token, here [an official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) recommend you to use MSAL to obtain the token you need.

> we recommend you use the supported Microsoft Authentication Libraries
> (MSAL) instead to acquire tokens and call secured web APIs. Also take
> a look at the sample apps that use MSAL.

I have [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65763064/14574199) which used msal.js to generate access token for calling graph api for azure key vault, the difference is the scopes, and according to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/privileged-identity-management/pim-apis#required-permissions), it says the api soope is :

```
Directory.AccessAsUser.All  Directory.Read.All  Directory.ReadWrite.All  PrivilegedAccess.ReadWrite.AzureAD
```

So you need to create an azure ad application and add above api permissions and change the 'scope' in the code. And if you need a sample in other program language, you can refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code#single-page-applications) to choose another sample.

Before you compose the code, I think you can generate a test token to test if this token could help you to call the api, using tools like postman.

[image]

Comment: Do you know if it would  be possible to create a token using just my username and password without using an app registration ? If i have to use app registraion, which may need tenant level permission that requires so many levels of approvals :(

Comment: It's necessary to register an azure ad app because the token is generated from msal which integrated with azure ad. And even your tenant admin has consented the users could create app, the api permissions are also needed to be approved by admin. https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2waP.png

Comment: Yea, I have done that process before so I am aware. Even to get just read AD access to SP, it took me ages for me to get approval. So there is no way I would be able to get a read/write permission. I am really suprised I can't generate a token just with  username and password in azure :((  I guess, at this point fetch the bearer token manually from developer console is the only option for me :((

Comment: Have you got a token from developer console successfully till now? I mean that the token you obtained in that way may not suitable for the api you wanna call because the token may have wrong scope. It sounds a pity for that.

Comment: yeah, I have been using the token from the developer console and activating PIM for a few days now. But it's a pain so wanted to automate it.

Comment: That's fine you got a useful token at least, and you need an application admin role to achieve your goal or get the help from admin. I think this question has reached the end :)