# Why doesn't my Azure Active Directory auth token contain permissions for MS Graph?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm working in Postman before I start writing app code so that I can get my head around what I'm actually supposed to be doing - it's educational; in actual app dev, I'll be using MSAL for auth.

In the meantime, I can't even manage to get a token that works.

My app on Azure has the `Calendar.Read` and `Calendar.ReadWrite` permissions set in the API Permissions blade of the Azure Portal.

I've created a client secret for the app (so using client credentials flow) and I'm providing the `/.default` scope per [this accepted answer on MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/256281/microsoft-azure-ad-jwt-token-is-missing-scope-info.html).

When I try to query MS graph at `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<my user id>/events` I get the error saying:

> The token contains no permissions, or permissions can not be understood

Sure enough, the token contains neither the `scp` or `roles` claims.

I've also referenced [csharpcorner](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/getting-started-with-microsoft-graph-api/) to get a token as well as [the actual documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/get-azure-active-directory-token) to configure the request in Postman.

I don't understand where I'm going wrong. As far as I can tell I'm doing everything the way I'm supposed to be but I'm just not getting anywhere.

Where am I going wrong? Have I missed something? Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Here's my jquery code from Postman:

```
var settings = {
  "url": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/redacted/oauth2/token",
  "method": "POST",
  "timeout": 0,
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  },
  "data": {
    "grant_type": "client_credentials",
    "client_id": "redacted",
    "client_secret": "redacted",
    "resource": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
    "scope": "./default"
  }
};

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you grant **admin consent** when adding `application permissions`?

Comment: @CarlZhao the delegated permissions have admin consent but I don't have proper access to grant admin consent on the application permissions (I'm not even sure if I need them in the first place)

Comment: `client_credentials` uses Application permissions exclusively. Delegated permissions can only be used with an authenticated user.

Comment: If my answer is helpful to you, you can [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it to end the thread.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Okay, that's the problem, you have not granted `Calendars.Read` or `Calendars.ReadWrite` **application permissions**.

Because you are using the client credential flow to get the token and call the `/users/{user id}` endpoint to list the events of other users. So you must grant application permissions and grant **admin consent** for that permission. Then your problem will be solved.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Take a look if you're using implicit flow otherwise, there's a max length issue and the content of the token will be truncated.

https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/issues/239

Answer (score 0):

Which language are you using? In my opinion, you can't use jquery to send an ajax request to obtain an access token, that should be a CORS error.

In the meanwhile, client credential flow should be used in daemon applications, but the code you provides are likely to be a single-page application. Here's a document contains many samples for different kind of applications and you may choose one to generate your access token.

[image]

Here's my [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65763064/14574199) on obtaining access token for calling key vault, you may refer to it. If I misunderstood in some place, pls point it out. You can also provide more details on your further issue.

=========================================================

frontend code, obtain access token from backend and calling graph api:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div id="subject"></div>
            <div>create time: <span id="cDateTime"></span></div>
            
        </div>
        <script src="../js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                initPage();
            });
            
            function initPage(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: "https://localhost:44343/",
                    type: 'get',
                    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                    success: function(data) {
                        callApi(data);
                    },
                    error: function(data) {
                        console.info(data);
                    }
                })
            }
            
            function callApi(accesstoken){
                $.ajax({
                    url: "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_id_here}/calendar/events",
                    type: 'get',
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: "Bearer " + accesstoken
                    },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data) {
                        var createdDateTime = data.value[0].createdDateTime;
                        var subject = data.value[0].subject;
                        $("#subject").html(subject);
                        $("#cDateTime").html(createdDateTime);
                    },
                    error: function(data) {
                        console.info(data);
                    }
                })
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

backend code(home controller), using client credential flow to generate access token, and send it to front end. Don't forget to deal with cores error if you choose to  use frontend-backend-separate.

```
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace crendentailflow_web_mvc.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public async Task<string> Index()
        {
            //I saved the client secret in azure key vault, and you can aslo use it directly
            const string secretName = "clientsecret";
            var kvUri = "https://vaultname.vault.azure.net/";
            var a = new DefaultAzureCredential();
            var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(kvUri), a);
            var secret = await client.GetSecretAsync(secretName);
            string secretVaule = secret.Value.Value;

            IConfidentialClientApplication app;
            app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create("azure_ad_app_client_id")
                    .WithClientSecret(secretVaule)
                    .WithAuthority(new Uri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/your_tenant_name.onmicrosoft.com"))
                    .Build();

            AuthenticationResult result = null;
            // don't forget to add api permission in azure portal
            string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
            result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
                    .ExecuteAsync();
            string accesstoken = result.AccessToken;
            return accesstoken;
        }
    }
}
```

dependencies:

```
<PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.4.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets" Version="4.1.0" />
```

Comment: So my intended use here is display a "live" shared calendar on a web interface. We want to set up TV screens in the office that shows a shared calendar. SPA is fine and I've looked at a lot of samples and I've been working from samples but even the samples here can't connect to my calendar so really I'm clutching at straws here... You can see this evident in the samples I've downloaded https://imgur.com/uwMVXvM

Comment: According to your words, it seems that it's better to use client credential flow to generate access token and calling the graph api to obtain calendar data so that you don't need to sign in your program(other flows provided by azure are required to sign in and then can got access token for calling api). Let me try to offer you a backend MVC program sample.